# Deploying Struts2 application on another machine

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

I am deploying a struts2 application on another machine sometimes application runs but sometime it gives the following error

```
Apr 9, 2012 2:12:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2 Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - [unknown location]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:839)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:131)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3709)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4363)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:627)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:511)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1231)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1471)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:824)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:350)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.createDocument(SAX2DOM.java:324)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.<init>(SAX2DOM.java:84)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:187)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:392)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerHandlerImpl.setResult(TransformerHandlerImpl.java:137)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.setup(DomHelper.java:213)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:198)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:189)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:175)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:830)
        ... 46 more Apr 9, 2012 2:12:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2 Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - [unknown location]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:839)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:131)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3709)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4363)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1247)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:377)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.createDocument(SAX2DOM.java:324)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.<init>(SAX2DOM.java:84)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:187)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:392)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerHandlerImpl.setResult(TransformerHandlerImpl.java:137)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.setup(DomHelper.java:213)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:198)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:189)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:175)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:830)
```

... 32 more

I am using Struts2 and apache tomcat 6.0.18 and netbeans 6.5 as ide
and struts.xml is shown below.

```
    <action name="HelloWorld" class="com.cdac.cloud.HelloWorld">
        <result name="successfullogin">/success.jsp</result>
         <result name="loginfailed">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>


    <action name="deletefile" class="com.cdac.cloud.HelloWorld" method="deleteFile">
        <result name="successfuldelete">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="exception">/error.jsp</result> 
    </action>


    <action name="fileUploadAction" class="com.cdac.cloud.HelloWorld" method="uploadFile">
        <result name="successfulupload">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="exception">/error.jsp</result> 
    </action>


     <action name="downloadfile" class="com.cdac.cloud.HelloWorld" method="downloadFile">
        <result name="successfuldownload" type="stream">/success.jsp
        <param name="contentType">${contentType}</param>
        <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${fileName}"</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
        </result>
        <result name="exception">/error.jsp</result> 
    </action>

    <action name="logout" class="com.cdac.cloud.HelloWorld" method="logout">
        <result name="successfullogout">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="exception">/error.jsp</result> 
    </action>

     <action name="goback" class="com.cdac.cloud.HelloWorld" method="listFiles">
        <result name="successback">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="exception">/error.jsp</result> 
    </action>

</package>
```

surprising part is whenever i restart netbeans and tomcat  my application runs and if i run another application than this first application stops running with above mentioned error

Comment: can you show your `struts.xml` file, seems like there is some issue in that.additionally please provide information about the env in which you are deploying your application.

Comment: which struts version you are using?

Comment: As already stated we will need to know more about the environment.  What version of glassfish? What version of struts2? What JARs are on your class path? Are you using maven? If so show the pom. web.xml may be relevant as well.

Comment: are you running this application from netbeans itself?

Comment: yes i am running this application from netbeans

Comment: Thanx all my problem get resolved after removing xercessimpl-2.8.1.jar from Library. I think there was some conflict between the two jars present in my project library and jdk library